# Web API Serialize XML

Tags: c#, xml, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to serialize XML using the web API, but I receive a null result.

Here is my XML:

http://pastebin.com/RxBPaZF5

Using XSD, I generated a class in Visual Studio:

http://pastebin.com/kUca0whm

Here is the code I am using:

```
public COM_Order GetOrderById(string orderId)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(m_UserName, m_Password);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
        };


        string url =  m_BaseUrl + String.Format("/rest/ecommerce.order/{0}", orderId);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<data>().Result;
            //result is null, even though valid JSON is returned
            return result.Items.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return null;


    }
```

Is there a problem with my class? I can also return JSON.

Comment: Have you checked you really certainly 100% get something back in result.Items?

Comment: Yes, the items object is null. There is a response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says response.Content.*ReadAsAsync*().Result;

Are your sure `result` is populated before you return it?
In the debugger you have one behaviour, outside another.

Try turning `ReadAsAsync` off to see if it is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. I added result after ReadAsAsync, however, I still have no result. It seems that it fails to add orders to my COM_Order collection.

Comment: I used other code that does WebRequest, without anything async, and it worked.